# How to customize tcp port number other than default (80)

Tags: c#

I'm using a web service and connect it using httpWebRequest.create api. If i change the TCP port number In IIS other than 80 then my application could not connect to it. How can i set port number in System.Url object as set in IIS so that my application can connect to web service.

Comment: Maybe include in your question that you're looking for a way to determine the port number IIS is set to at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

You'd normally do this by appending the port like so:

```
http://www.example.com:81/path/to/page
```

Comment: its ok but how  i'll know what port number is set to IIS. I've to query this port number at run time so that i can append port number in URL accordingly

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to connect to a web service but you won't necessarily know in advance what port it is going to be running on?

Comment: Suppose my web service abc is mapped to default web site in IIS. i acess this web service using http://localhost/abc/abc.asmx. At that time i able to connect with this service.Assume one goes to IIS and under default web sites changes port number to 90 from default value 80 and restart IIS. Now i come to my application but this time it didn't connect to web service because i'm still using http://localhost/abc/abc.asmx without knowing what is new port number. My question is is there any way to find changed port number so that i can modify requested web service address with new portnumber in IIS

Answer (score 4):

use URI in form `http://example.com:8080/` where 8080 can be any other

Answer (score 0):

I think, if the Uri of your webservice is http://webservice/ then you might just do http://webservice:1234 where 1234 is your new port..

Comment: its ok but how  i'll know what port number is set to IIS. I've to query this port number at run time so that i can append port number in URL accordingly

Comment: To query at runtime, you need to have another web service which supplies ports for known web services. IMHO, there is no another alternative, since you cannot perform any communication without knowing ports.

Comment: Suppose my web service abc is mapped to default web site in IIS. i acess this web service using http://localhost/abc/abc.asmx. At that time i able to connect with this service.Assume one goes to IIS and under default web sites changes port number to 90 from default value 80 and restart IIS. Now i come to my application but this time it didn't connect to web service because i'm still using http://localhost/abc/abc.asmx without knowing what is new port number. My question is is there any way to find changed port number so that i can modify requested web service address with new portnumber in IIS

Answer (score 0):

- Using `WebRequest.Create` with [string parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc.aspx) :

  ```
  WebRequest.Create("http://{server}:{port});
  ```
- Using `WebRequest.Create` with [uri parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0aa3d588.aspx) :

  ```
  Uri myUri = new Uri("http://{server}:{port}");
  WebRequest.Create(Uri);
  ```

Comment: its ok but how  i'll know what port number is set to IIS. I've to query this port number at run time so that i can append port number in URL accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Determining the port of an IIS that runs on a remote machine is not easy. Either you will need to have a different way of communicating the configuration (like a service), or use a portscanner that will check all possible ports (not recommended).

**but**, if the IIS is running on the local machine, you can use the `appcmd` command to get a list of sites running in IIS.

```
appcmd list site
```

If you want to do this programmatically in C#, you could do something along the lines of:

```
// Setup ProcessStartInfo
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
processInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe");
processInfo.Arguments = "list site";
processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

// Start the process
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = processInfo; 
process.Start(processInfo);

// Capture the output and wait for exit
var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
process.WaitForExit();

// Parse the output
var ports = Regex.Matches(output, ":([0-9]+):");
foreach (Match port in ports)
{
    // TODO: Do something with the ports here
    Console.WriteLine(port.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value);
}
```